# pgr_dijkstraCost() Many-to-Many exceeding RAM disponibility

Tags: qgis, pgrouting, in-memory, dijkstra

I am working with PostGreSQL 9.6, pgRouting 2.4.1 and PostGis 2.3.1 on a Linux with 3Gb of RAM and 4Gb of SWAP.

I am trying to launch the following query :

```
SELECT start_vid as building, end_vid as plant, agg_cost as junction_length from pgr_dijkstraCost
(
'SELECT gid as id, i as source , j as target , length as cost from   network_edges'
, array(SELECT id from "network_nodes" where buildingID!='NULL')
, array(SELECT id from "network_nodes" where plant_name!='NULL')
, false
)
```

The network_nodes as 135 000 row and the network_edges as 270 000 rows. Every time I launch the query, it exceed the RAM in 30s and I get disconnected from the database. I found a some informations on the web : https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/kernel-resources.html#LINUX-MEMORY-OVERCOMMIT. I tried to minimize the value of work_mem, shared_buffer and max_connection_number but it didn't change anything.

Is there any way that I can limit the memory usage of this query, even if it takes longer or does it need to load everything in memory ?

The only solution that I see is to reduce the number of building and then launch this request multiple times.

Comment: This might not be related, bu your array filter I think should be  buildingID IS NOT NULL,   plant_name IS NOT NULL..  Unless you actually store the string value 'NULL' in your columns for buildingID and plant_name.

Comment: I do not think that it's related but thanks for the infomation anyway !

Comment: In order to see if it takes less ressources, I created a table with 2 columns : the first one contains a buildingID and the second one an array of plant's ids which are close to the corresponding building. My problem is, I can't figure out how to enter the parameters in pgr_dijkstraCost() ?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and I solved it like this:

You can simply break the job into pieces, by running more than one queries and creating more than one tables. For example, if the values of your "buildingID" are i.e. from 1 to 10000, you can **2 queries instead of one**. Run a first query like this:

```
CREATE TABLE results1of2 as
(
SELECT start_vid as building, end_vid as plant, agg_cost as junction_length from pgr_dijkstraCost
(
'SELECT gid as id, i as source , j as target , length as cost from   network_edges'
, array(SELECT id from "network_nodes" where buildingID<5000)
, array(SELECT id from "network_nodes" where plant_name IS NOT NULL)
, false
)
);
```

and then a second query like this:

```
CREATE TABLE results2of2 as
(
SELECT start_vid as building, end_vid as plant, agg_cost as junction_length from pgr_dijkstraCost
(
'SELECT gid as id, i as source , j as target , length as cost from   network_edges'
, array(SELECT id from "network_nodes" where buildingID>=5000)
, array(SELECT id from "network_nodes" where plant_name IS NOT NULL')
, false
)
);
```

Now you can create your final table with a query such as:

```
CREATE TABLE results as
(
SELECT * from results1of2
UNION ALL
SELECT * from results2of2
);
```

If the problem persists, you can break the job to more pieces i.e. try making **3 queries** now. In the **1st** query set: buildingID<3000, in the **2nd** query set buildingID>=3000 and buildingID<6000 and in the **3d** query set buildingID>=6000. If you keep running out of memory, break it to more pieces (4,5,...), until your queries can run.